# Python script hangs on ubuntu server using selenium firefox driver

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-13.10

I'm trying to take screenshots of some webpages.  I opted for selenium and firefox.  I'm using  xvfb and setting an environment variable for the display.

The script works fine without xvfb on OS X desktop. However on the server the script hangs after `webdriver.Firefox()` is issued as if the python script is no longer executing. No exception is ever raised and firefox is still active in my process list.

Setup:

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
export DISPLAY=:10
```

test.py

```
from selenium import webdriver

print 'start'
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
print 'Hello?'
firefox.quit()
print 'done!'
```

output:

```
start
cursor winks tauntingly
```

I Had the same problem with Chrome. Also tried the phantomJs flash fork, this was successful but did not capture flash content.

starting independently firefox gives

```
    (process:3278): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' f       failed
    Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":10".
    Error: Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory.
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned     error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
    ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No   such file or directory
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
    ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default

(firefox:3278): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
    //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

Please help

Thanks!